# Is there a formula of coefficients of Newton-Cotes Method in numerical intergation?

Tags: numerical-methods

We know the coefficients of Newton-Cotes method in numerical integration are:

2-points        $ 0.5$ ,     $0.5$

3-points        $ 1/6$,    $2/3$,   $ 1/6$

4-points         $1/8$,     $3/8$,    $3/8$,    $1/8$

and so on

I ask if there is a formula of all coefficients in this method.

Comment: Yes, for example the trapezoid-rule and the simpson-rule.

Comment: sorry, I ask if there is a formula or equation which gives these coefficients

Comment: Oops, I misread the question, sorry.

Comment: The coefficients can be calculated using that the integration has to be exact upto some degree. This can be turned into a general formula.

Comment: I think, the values for $3$-points have actually to be $1/6,4/6,1/6$ because the sum must be $1$, if the interval [$0,1$] is chosen. But if [$-1,1$] is chosen, the given sequence is OK, but the $2$-point sequence should be $1,1$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited this value and the others

Answer (score 1):

Maybe read: http://people.clas.ufl.edu/kees/files/NewtonCotes.pdf

It presents a method easily convertible to MATLAB that can be used to generate the coefficients:

```
function q = NewtonCotesCoefficients(degree)

  q = 0:degree;
  m = fliplr(vander(q));
  for ii = 0: degree
    b(ii + 1) = degree^(ii + 1)/(ii + 1);
  end
  q = m'\b';
end
```